# Can the admin console colors be changes on Wildfly?

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8

Ive checked the documents but cant find any advice on changing the admin console colors. My plan would be a different color per environment - dev, test, ...

If it cant I could change it through a browser plugin

Answer (score 1):

Console specific jar is available under '/org/jboss/as/console/' module. To make changes in header and footer you can update this jar file. If you want to customize console further then you can make changes in [source code](https://github.com/hal/core) and build your custom jar. hope it helps.